# C# List Group And Subgroup to TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, treeview

I have a custom item:

```
List<Class_Items_Data> All_Items_List = new List<Class_Items_Data>();

public class Class_Items_Data
{
public string item_category { get; set; }
public string item_sub_category { get; set; }
public string item_name { get; set; }
}
```

for example :

```
item_category = "Food"    , item_sub_category = "Main Dish" , item_name = "A" };
item_category = "Beverage", item_sub_category = "Hot Drink" , item_name = "B" };
item_category = "Food"    , item_sub_category = "Soup"      , item_name = "C" };
item_category = "Beverage", item_sub_category = "Cold Drink", item_name = "D" }
```

I want to put them in Treeview in order to show me the following Result:

[image]

**Edit#**

i'm Using Winform

i have tried this so far  ( Message Boxes Showing Correct Values )

```
  var ItemsGroups = All_Items_List 
    .GroupBy(x => new { Group = x.item_category_group, Category = x.item_category})
    .GroupBy(x => new { Group = x.Key.Group }).OrderBy(x => x.Key.Group);

            foreach (var Group in ItemsGroups)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Group : " + Group.Key.Group);
                foreach (var Category in Group)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("SubCategory : " + Category.Key.Category);
                    foreach (var Item in Category)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Item : " + Item.item_name_original);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: WinForms, WPF, Html, something else? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thank u for your note, i edited the question

Comment: The property names in `Class_Items_Data` do not match the names in your `ItemsGroups` LINQ query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loops to

```
foreach (var Group in ItemsGroups) {
    TreeNode groupNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(Group.Key.Group);
    foreach (var Category in Group) {
        TreeNode categoryNode = groupNode.Nodes.Add(Category.Key.Category);
        foreach (var Item in Category) {
            categoryNode.Nodes.Add(Item.item_name_original);
        }
    }
}
```